# MooTools: "this" element on form

Tags: javascript, html, mootools

http://jsfiddle.net/DnBsR/

As you can see in jsfiddle, the affect for the "Name" input box works as planned:

- If you click on it, it slides so you can see the label.
- If you then click off it, it slides back.
- If you enter text into the box, it does not slide back, until nothing is in there again.

This effect is exactly what I want (forget about it not covering the whole label etc for now).

However, I will be having more than one form input box, as can be seen.  What do you add to the MooTools so it works for each input box, rather than just the one? Something along the lines of "this"? Can't work it out...

Also, if anyone wants to make the current MooTools better, feel free, as that can probably be done much easier...

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

First, you have to use `$$` selector to work with the collection of elements (and not just a single one). And as you cannot have two (or more) elements with the same ID in DOM, you should use some other means to group them - classes, I suppose, are the most common way to do that.

Second, you should use `this` variable (instead of trying to walk the DOM again and again) inside event handlers, as it will correspond to the target element.

Finally, you can (and should) chain the event attachments. Like this:

```
$$('.element').addEvent('focus', function(){
    var input_value = this.value;
    if (input_value == '') {
        this.morph({
          'left': '60px',
          'width': '256px'
        });
    }
}).addEvent('blur', function(){
    var input_value = this.value;
    if (input_value === '') {
      this.morph({
        'left': '16px',
        'width': '300px'
      });
    }
});
```

Here's the [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DnBsR/3/) to play with. )

Comment: Also - is there anyway to edit the CSS of the label? Like when you click on the "Name" input box, the box slides (as it does now), and the text color of the label changes to say red? Again, individually for each one?

Comment: @Alias In the example you can get the `label` for each element just with `this.getPrevious('label')` expression, and set its style right away with `this.getPrevious('label').setStyle('color', 'red')`. Check the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DnBsR/5/).

Answer (score 1):

Just use this:
http://jsfiddle.net/DnBsR/2/
Explanation:
With $$(selector), you can just parse normal css selectors, so this one selects all input elements of #myform.
We loop over them with .each, and in the loop we add an event handler to them.
Since we cannot use $('element') anymore in the handler, we just use this, which points to the element the event was fired from.